# Why does gradient descent gives me much better Relative Squared Error then the Least Squares approach?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, gradient-descent

Am I doing regression task with 7 dependent variables and 10000 data points. The SGD gives me 22% of mean absolute percentage error on test and train dataset. And Least Squares method using numpy [scipy.optimize.least_squares](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.least_squares.html) give me only 58% (I have tried different settings.). I thought that Least Squares should give the same or better performance with such size dataset. What can be the reasons?

Comment: What is your loss function for running SGD?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is that the two metrics, [mean absolute percentage error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_absolute_percentage_error) (MAPE) and [mean square error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error) (MSE) are optimising to different targets. Improving one can be done at the expense of the other.

As a simple example, consider this data:

```
x = [ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5]
y = [ 3,  5, 10, 10, 11, 15]
```

The best fit mean squared error (MSE) for a line on this data is $\hat{y} = 2.23x + 3.43$, which has MSE of $1.18$, and a mean absolute percentage error (MAPE) of $11.0$%.

The best fit mean absolute percentage loss for a line on this data is $\hat{y} = 2.35x + 2.99$, which has a MSE of $1.24$, and a MAPE of $8.34$%.

You can see that optimising for MAPE gives a worse MSE, and vice-versa.

The difference can get extreme when there is a large range for y values (in terms of orders of magnitude covered), because optimising for MAPE will favour being more accurate on small values at the expense of larger ones. So if we change y to be:

```
y = [ 1,  2, 10, 10, 11, 20]
```

Then optimising mean abs percentage gives the line $\hat{y} = 3.78x + 1.05$ with MSE $7.09$ and MAPE $21.9$%. But optimising for mean square error gives $\hat{y} = 3.49x + 0.286$ with MSE  $4.56$ and MAPE $62.9$% - this is a larger difference, and I suspect that your data has a large range of target variable causing a similar effect.

---

You can potentially get closer results using the Least Squares regressor by using a transformed target variable $z = log(y)$ and transforming back at the end. This still won't be quite the same, but it does reduce the difference significantly - in my last example if I try this, I get MAPE $24.2$% - compared to $21.9$% for optimising MAPE directly.

Comment: Good answer and I apreciating your help, so I will accept, but the reason was actually the other. In the begining I have to notice that we can use MAPE in the least squares not only MSE. So the reason: I have already  log transformed the data and then for gradient descent I have used a trick. I have used three losses in three steps ro learn better: mean relative squared error - >  abs relative error - >  relative error of exp of prediction / exp of real value(to go back from log) and for least squares I have used just mean squared relative error as loss without exp. And that is important.